# How to create a list for data.d in ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am fairly new to AJAX. I am getting a data in 'data.d' and need to create a list for each item I receive.
Also, I am not able to add HTML tags inside the `<script>` . Please help

success: function (data, status) {
                    try
                    {

```
                    var issues = data.d;
                    for (var i = 0; i<issues.length; i++)
                    {

                        $("#div1").html(issues);

                    }
```

I need data.d formatted as :

Issue List :

```
1. Issue 1
2. Issue 2 ..
```

Comment: what does the data.d look like right now?

Comment: Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 ...